# Where functions take lifetimes for returned values

Tags: rust, enums, lifetime

I have this in separated modul:

```rust
pub enum CatchedResult<'a> {
    Success(&'a str),
    Err(&'a str)
}

pub fn err_catcher<'a>(catched: fn() -> CatchedResult<'a>) {
    // ...
    catched();
    // ...
    catched();
    // ...
    // ...
}
```

And this in program that uses the modul:

```rust
fn main() {
    err_catcher(catched);
}

fn catched<'a>() -> CatchedResult<'a> {
   //...
   //returning CatchedResult
}
```

I understad that `CatchedResult` need lifetime for his `&str` and for him self.
In second code, I dont understad where is `'a` taken. **Where is `'a` taken?**

Comment: What do you mean by "where `'a` is taken"?

Comment: And me I don't understand your question. Tips: don't use lifetime when learning rust

Comment: Without lifetime => error. Taken => Its lifetime of what, how long it will life?

Comment: @Stargateur means you'll use an owned `String`. The lifetime in your function can be any.

Comment: Why to use `String` (heap) when I can use `&str` (stack)? How any wtf?

Comment: String data will hardly ever be on the stack. It's usually either in the static read-only data segment or the heap. But I get your point – using a `&str` can save heap allocations in some cases, which can improve performance. However, in practice that hardly ever matters. For newer Rust programmers, it's recommended not to use lifetimes on structs, and instead uses owned data types. In almost all cases, this will be fast enough.

Comment: You can think of lifetime parameters like `<'a>` as template parameters. So in this case it is any lifetime b/c you have no constraints on `'a`. If you had a parameter that was also `'a` then you would be constraining the input and output lifetimes to be the same.

Comment: Side note: the past participle of *catch* is *caught*, not *catched*.

Comment: Just to elaborate a little on what @PiRocks said: a function's generic parameters (whether lifetime, type or constant) are resolved at the call-site, which is to say that the caller gets to determine their concrete value.  Hence a parameter that is not constrained by one of the function's arguments is free for the caller to make any value of its choosing; for a lifetime, this means that the only (safe) implementation is something `'static` (in which case the signature may as well use that instead).

Comment: It would be interesting to see your implementation of `catched`, since any `CatchedResult`that it creates must surely have either `'static` lifetime or else a lifetime that is scoped within the function call (else, with no inputs to the function, where have the `&str` references come from?).  For example, if you allocate a `String` in the function body and create a `CatchedResult` that references into it, then such referenced `&str` will deallocate when that `String` is dropped on going out of scope (e.g. when the function returns).

Comment: @eggyal What means signiture in this case? If I returning `CatchedResult` with reference to `String` I must copy the `String`. But the returning in my case looks like this: `return CaughtResult::Err("Error: First number is not valid")`. If I use lifetime `'a` (everywhere rust compiler need some lifetime) all work, but I have problem understand why.

Comment: String literals like `"Error: First number is not valid"` are of type `&'static str`, which is why `'a` works in that case (but you may as well instead return `CatchedResult<'static>` to be more clear about what's happening).

Comment: @eggyal Thanks, I finally moustly  understand. So if I use `&str`(as msgs for enum) insted of `String` (as msgs ...). And lifetimes I solve with this: `CatchedResult<'static>` . Than it will be potencialy faster than with `String`?

Comment: It indeed avoids the allocation and copying that would be involved in using `String`, but as @SvenMarnach said earlier, the performance cost of that is unlikely to be material.

Comment: In that case, you actually don't need to the lifetime parameter on the struct. You could instead use `&'static str` as the type in the variants, since it's the only lifetime you can reasonably use there anyway.